# SharePoint 2013 ULS log tracing from custom solution missing

Tags: logging, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a custom solution deployed to farm that write logs to ULS by extending SPDiagnosticsServiceBase class. The solution is working just fine and the logs were present last week but now no logs coming from said solution and no one changed any setting. ULS logs are still being filled by other services just fine.

What I done so far:

- Central Admin > Monitoring > Diagnostic logging > Least critical level set to verbose
  (I don't expect this to be much help since we can see verbose logs from other services anyway)
- Check via PowerShell SPTraceV4 service - it is online

Answer (score 1):

If you did it yourself, run the code in a Console Application (x64) and only then pack in Visual Web Part, Event Reciever or Custom Timer Job and using the code:

```
try
   {
    //your code here
   }
 catch (Exception ex)
   {
     File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\error.txt", ex.ToString());
   }
```

Conduct self-logging by creating files and lines inside them with code execution.